# How to efficiently pass a string to a function if I will certainly copy it? C++20

Tags: c++, std, c++20, stdstring, string-view

I would like to know how to properly handle a string input in a function, if I know I will have to make a copy inside of it to place it inside a container.

I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
void foo(const string& s){
    container.push(s);
}
```

But if I pass a char* string I will make 2 copies, first when calling foo, then when passing it to a container.

My second idea was to use a string_view, as it is often said, that if you can use a view, you should. So my second version of the function looked like this:

```
void foo2(string_view s){
    container.push(string(s));
}
```

Ok, now I will make only a single copy no matter what type of string I am given.
But then I started thinking, why couldn't I just accept a string as an argument to a function, simplifying it like this:

```
void foo3(string s){
    container.push(std::move(s));
}
```

But now I have to make sure, that my container properly utilizes move semantics so it doesn't end up making another copy! As this container object is a templated type it means using perfect forwarding and so on, which is whole lot of work in itself.

At this point I have no idea which option to choose, so I would like to ask you for some advice. I also feel like I am way overthinking this, as this probably won't have that much of a performance impact in the end, but I would like to do it *right*. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The third option would be my choice. But remember that this stuff is not normally a deal breaker, so convenience is also a factor.

Comment: Related https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/364094/52859

Answer (score 8):

You know that you definitely need a `std::string` in the end. Not something string like, exactly a `std::string`. In this case it doesn't make sense to take as argument anything else than a `std::string`. There are exceptions to this, e.g. if all of your exposed interface you use `std::string_view` then it might make sense to do here as well.

Now the choices are `const std::string&` (lvalue ref), `std::string&&` (rvalue ref) and `std::string` (value). In this case where you know you need a new object to pass to the level below the **recommended** one is: **value + `std::move`**.

This way:

- if the user has something else than a `std::string` you get 1 conversion + 1 move
- if the user has `std::string` you get 1 copy + 1 move (or 1 move + 1 move if the user does `std::move` at the call site).

> But now I have to make sure, that my container properly utilizes move semantics

No, not "now". This shouldn't be the point where you start to consider move semantics for your container. A container most likely should have proper move semantics just on the merit of it being ... well a container. You don't want to copy 5k elements when you could have moved them instead.

Answer (score 5):

A fourth option would be to use perfect forwarding and pass the arguments to `foo` *as-is* to the container's `emplace`/`emplace_back` function:

```cpp
template<class... Args>
requires std::constructible_from<std::string, Args...>
void foo4(Args&&... args){ // a forwarding reference pack
    container.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

1. If you pass a temporary `std::string` to `foo4`, it'll use the `std::string` move constructor. Nothing else.
2. If you pass an lvalue reference to `foo4`, it'll use the `std::string` copy constructor. Nothing else.
3. If you pass other arguments that can be used to construct a `std::string`, like a `std::string_view`, it'll be constructed in-place in the container. Not even a copy or move will be needed.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q8eG3on9q)

---

You could do equally well for the first two cases above by manually creating the overloads needed to avoid unneeded instantiations.

```cpp
void foo4(const std::string& f) { container.push(f); } // one copy
void foo4(std::string&& f) { container.push(std::move(f)); } // one move
```

It would however not allow for the the third case to be as effective. If you don't care about, or don't want to support, the third case, you could go for the two overloads that mimics what a *copy constructor*/*move constructor* pair does. Since you asked about how to  *"efficiently pass a string"* I think that adding an overload is a small price to pay.

Comment: and if you pass sth not convertible to string, you'll get an ugly error ;) Though granted, the post is tagged C++20, concepts might help here ;)

Comment: @alagner If anyone is afraid of terribly ugly error messages then they shouldn't write C++ code in the first place.

Comment: @alagner Yes, `constructible_from` could help to make error messages nicer.

Comment: @alagner There, just came back and added `constructible_from`.